# How could I perform a pan to Camera in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

In apps such as Instagram, you can pan left (on home screen) to show the camera VC. The camera comes in as you pan.  How can I implement this in React Native?

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for pan events with [`PanResponder`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) and navigate to desired screen or run an action or similar to open up the camera.

> ### PanResponder
>
> `PanResponder` reconciles several touches into a single gesture. It
>   makes single-touch gestures resilient to extra touches, and can be
>   used to recognize simple multi-touch gestures.
>
> By default, `PanResponder` holds an `InteractionManager` handle to
>   block long-running JS events from interrupting active gestures.
>
> It provides a predictable wrapper of the responder handlers provided
>   by the [gesture responder system](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system). For each handler, it provides a
>   new gestureState object alongside the native event object:
>
> ```
> onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PanResponder`'s `onPanResponderGrant` and `onPanResponderRelease` events to check if the movement is a left pan, then open the camera with [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) or Expo's [Camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera) / [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/sdk/imagepicker#expoimagepickerlaunchcameraasyncoptions) modules.

Working demo: https://snack.expo.io/SJCGFC477

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, PanResponder, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { ImagePicker, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderGrant: e => {
      this.start = e.nativeEvent.pageX;
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: e => {
      if (this.start - e.nativeEvent.pageX > 100) {
        Promise.all([
          Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA),
          Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL),
        ]).then(([{ status: status1 }, { status: status2 }]) => {
          if (status1 !== 'granted' && status2 !== 'granted') {
            Alert.alert('Permission not granted');
            return;
          }
          ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync().catch(e =>
            Alert.alert('Failed to launch camera', e.message)
          );
        });
      }
    },
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <Text
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: '50%' }}>
        Pan left to open camera
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely the simplest way to accomplish this would be to render a view *offscreen* which has the same dimensions as your current view. Presumably using `Dimensions.get('window')` but your use case might differ slightly.

The key to setting it offscreen would be to position it absolutely, and set the value for `left` to the negative value of your screen width. However, to accomplish the transition, you'd want to have this value be an `Animated.Value` initialized to that negative screen width I'd mentioned.

Finally, as others have suggested, you'll need to implement a `PanResponder` on your initially visible view that would change the value of the `left` style on the absolutely positioned view with the camera. You'd want that camera view to be already active so your transition would look smooth.

Here's some pseudocode, I could help with a more fleshed out solution if this is the path you'd want to pursue for this question

```
// in constructor
this.state = {
  leftValue: new Animated.Value(-screenWidth)
}

// in render
<View style={styles.initialView} />
<Animated.View
  style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: this.state.leftValue,
    width: screenWidth,
    height: screenHeight,
  }}
>
  {cameraImplementation}
</Animated.View>
```